# Positioning images so they match their width and height

Tags: html, css, positioning

Hello I am trying to position my images following this picture but they do not look the same . Can anyone give me a tip please.
[This is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8zgn.png)

[And this is how my version looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J57Af.png)

This is my code

```
<img src="img3.png" alt="img3" width="30%" height="364px">

<img src="img2.png" alt="img2" width="30%" height="590px">

<img src="img3.png" alt="img3" width="30%" height="364px">

<img src="img2.png" alt="img2" width="30%" height="590px">

<img src="img3.png" alt="img3" width="30%" height="364px">

<img src="img2.png" alt="img2" width="30%" height="590px">
```

Comment: Normally you'd use a responsive grid for this and fit your images to it. Flexbox would suit nicely.

Comment: You tagged your question with CSS but I don't see any. CSS would fix this.

Comment: check flex box wrapping columns layout: http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide the site into three columns.

Column 1 contains one small and one tall image same goes for column 2 and column 3.

Then it should be something like this:

```
<div class="columns">
<img class="imgcolumnsmall" src="img3.png" alt="img3" width="30%" height="364px">

<img class="imgcolumntall" src="img2.png" alt="img2" width="30%" height="590px">
</div>

<div class="columns">
<img class="imgcolumnsmall" src="img3.png" alt="img3" width="30%" height="364px">

<img  class="imgcolumntall"src="img2.png" alt="img2" width="30%" height="590px">
</div>

<div class="columns">
<img class="imgcolumnsmall" src="img3.png" alt="img3" width="30%" height="364px">

<img class="imgcolumntall" src="img2.png" alt="img2" width="30%" height="590px">
</div>
```

You can ofcourse make CSS for each column individually calling them ´column1´ etc.

For the CSS it's quite easy:

```
.columns {
float:left;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #ff00ff;
}

img.imgcolumntall {
display: inline;
width: 30%;
height: 590px;
}

img.imgcolumnsmall {
display: inline;
width: 30%;
height: 364px;
}
```